# react-native-incall-manager 4.0.0 Android error JDK

Tags: react-native, lambda, java-8

Error after upgrading react-native-incall-manager to version 4.0.0 I have an error on Android regarding JDK. It's not supporting lambda expressions.It is very strange, because JDK 1.8 is set in the project settings.

**Logs from my latop:**

`openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08 LTS`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.54+25-CA (build 11.0.14.1+1-LTS)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.54+25-CA (build 11.0.14.1+1-LTS, mixed mode`

**REACT-NATIVE ERROR:**

> ProximityManager.java:51: error: lambda expressions are not supported
> in -source 7
> UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(() -> {
> (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
> /Users/dragostodoroscean/Desktop/Work/freedom-mobile/node_modules/react-native-incall-manager/android/src/main/java/com/zxcpoiu/incallmanager/InCallManagerModule.java:196:
> error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
> UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(() -> {
> ^   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

**ANDROID STUDIO ERROR**

> UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(() -> {
> ^
> (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

**IMAGE JDK 1.8 IS SET**

[image: IMAGE - JDK 1.8 IS SET]

Can someone tell me please what I did wrong ? I didn't find a solution for couple of days.

P.S. I'm trying to upgrade because InCallManager.setSpeakerForceOn() or setSpeakerOn() doesn't work on Android 11.

Thanks.

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: I fixed it by setting JDK 1.8 for react-native-incall-manager on the Android Studio Modules

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with react-native-keychain. Solution was, go to the node_module, in android/build.grade, add:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

and then use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to save the modified change to the library